# Does flurry analytics support iconic app on Huawei device without playstore/ GMS services?

Tags: ionic-framework, flurry, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

Flurry analytics is used in one of the iconic app that is published on play store and work fine on non Huawei devices. Now releasing this app on Huawei app gallery and Huawei devices which doesn't support play store and GMS services. So will this flurry plugin work fine in this iconic app on Huawei device with no play services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer to the [documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/) of the Flurry SDK and the official Ionic plugin [page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/flurry-analytics).

The Flurry SDK documentation says it is just recommended to use one GMS dependency, namely ads. If the app heavily relies on the integration of Google Mobile Ads, this specific functionality would only work partially because Huawei devices without GMS cannot connect to Google's API in order to receive the GAID.

What does that mean?

The GAID's main functionality is to give users personalized ads. In case you are **not using Google Mobile Ads or other Google services** like Firebase for example, your **app should run perfectly fine**. Moreover, I do also not see any dependencies required to be integrated with the Flurry plugin from Ionic.

Nevertheless, if you need personalized ads, Huawei has its own [Ads Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050437673) (available for Cordova but it can be implemented with Ionic) which replaces the GAID with the OAID. You do also have the ability to test the app out for yourself if you register as Huawei developer and have a look at the [Cloud Debug](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug) service.

This service lets you upload an apk to test it on a real HMS only device in one of Huawei's labs. After you finished testing, the device returns to its original state and all of your configurations will be deleted for a next user.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
The brand new version of Cordova Analytics plugin is [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050134727#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050139465__section222244042715), [added Ionic support](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/integrating-plugin-0000001051749125#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001051749125__section588211123316) with ionic-native wrapper and typescript support.

---

As far as I know, Huawei will update the Cordova plug-in version that supports TypeScript by the end of July to August. Then Ionic can be supported on Huawei device and Sample Code will also be provided. Please follow [Developer Support](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/overview/HMS-Core-Plugin).